# Why is Edmund being a young watch commander a good story lead?

Tags: plot-explanation, la-confidential

In *L.A Confidential* (1997), before discussing the title for the story with Smith, a reporter had a
conversation with Sgt Edmund and a photographer at the doorway of the
party hall:

> Reporter: Aren't you young to be watch commander?
>
> Edmund: It's only tonight. The married men have Christmas Eve off.
>
> Reporter: **That's a good lead for the story**.
>
> Photographer: Sure.

Why is Edmund being a young watch commander a good story lead?

Comment: Because it's a moderately interesting factoid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [tabloid journalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabloid_journalism), truth isn't the main goal. Anything can start and feed a story, as long as people want to read it. It's still the same nowadays though. In this case, if anything happens during that night, it can be sold on the frontpage with a voluntarily twisted eye on the story/background.

> "*Confidential*" was a magazine published quarterly from December 1952 to August 1953 and then bi-monthly until it ceased publication in 1978. It was founded by Robert Harrison and is considered a pioneer in scandal, gossip and exposé journalism. (from [Confidential - the magazine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidential_(magazine)))

In the movie, Sgt Vincennes feeds classified information to a tabloid magnate, Sid Hudgens. It's said to be inspired by the story of [Robert Harrison and his publications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidential_(magazine)#Portrayal_in_other_media).